# What is the opposite of an in-house application?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In my company we refer to applications that we created as "in-house" or "enterprise" applications.  I would like to refer to all applications a user could use... *excluding in-house applications*.

My first thought is "out-of-house applications".  However, this sounds silly.  Is there a better term to use for this collection of applications?

Comment: Maybe outsourced, hired-out, contracted. Out-of-house makes sense to me though

Comment: Opposite of custom software: *canned* software.  For example, a library of functions.  As opposed to writing your own custom modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In formal language, like a report to management or a committee, I would refer to "internal" and "non-internal" applications, because I like the symmetry, but "internal" and "external" would be equally acceptable. You could also call them "third-party applications".

A company that doesn't want to custom develop software *internally*, or *in-house* might *out-source* the software by hiring another firm to develop it to specification. Most software in used in business is
*commercial, off-the-shelf* software, or *COTS*, meaning generic software made by another company, like Microsoft Office. This is also called *shrink-wrap* software. Some *externally developed* software, especially some *enterprise applications* are *vendor-provided* and sold by the company that makes the software with the expectation the software or configuration will be customized.

- Developed by the company itself: internally developed, internal, custom, in-house, in-sourced, home-grown
- Bespoke developed by another company, to specifications: out-sourced
- Already-made software purchased from a re-seller: COTS, off-the-shelf, shrink-wrap
- Software purchased directly from the company that makes it: vendor-provided

Comment: COTS is what i would use.

Comment: @kyle-williamson, TurtleZero I think *Most software in used in business is commercial, off-the-shelf software, or COTS* is strong statement without references - Linux, Apache web-servers, Java, etc. And, I think the "opposite of an in-house software" = COTS + open-source software. COTS does not cover the latter.

Comment: @k1eran You make a good point, however,  guess I see FOSS as a different property that can apply to all of these. In-house, out-sourced, and commercially developed software can all be open-sourced. Feel free to edit the answer to capture the meaning that you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

They are **third-party applications**.

> In commerce, a "third-party source" means a supplier (or service provider) who is not directly controlled by either the seller (first party) or the customer/buyer (second party) in a business transaction [...]
> In Information Technology, a "third-party source" is a supplier of software (or a computer accessory) which is independent of the supplier and customer of the major computer product(s).
>
> — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_source

From [Apple's perspective](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201777):

> A third-party product is one that's made by a vendor other than Apple. Learn how to find and get help with third-party products.

Comment: But, who is the third party in Kyle's case?  Kyle's company = 1st party.  The company who wrote the application = 2nd party.  3rd party = ?

Comment: I would suggest that **second-party applications** would be better.  Same source as above (Wikipedia).

Comment: @thomj1332 I added a bit more from the wikipedia article. The 2nd party is the user or customer (who may be a department/person in the same organisation as the company developing the "in-house" apps).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to publications, companies refer to ***internal*** and ***external*** publications.

I think you could make application (wink) to applications.